# rabbitmq cli error getting messages

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to consume the messages from the CLI application (`rabbitmqadmin`) using the following command:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin --host rabbitmq get queue=test requeue=false
*** [{key_missing,ackmode}]
```

I have seen in working before, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong at the moment.

I am using rabbitmq 3.7.2. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with ackmode=ack_requeue_false instead of requeue=false

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/521#issuecomment-352178039

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the raabitmq-server version and the raabitmqadmin version must be same. 
In case, you have upgraded your raabitmq from an earlier version to 3.7.2 then you need to replace the older rabbitmqadmin version with the current version (should be same as currently running raabitmq-server version)

For installation of raabitmqadmin correct version, you can refer https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

You can also directly download the binary **rabbitmqadmin** from the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.2/bin/rabbitmqadmin